# Operators on Hilbert spaces and essentially bounded functions.

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

Are there some relationships between operators on Hilbert spaces (linear, bounded, self-adjoint, positive) and essentially bounded functions? Suggestions of books and websites, as well as any explanations, are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One direction.  Let our hilbert space be $H = L^2(X,\mathcal F, \mu)$.  Let $\phi : X \to \mathbb C$ be a measurable function.  Define the "multiplication" operator $T$ on $H$ by
$$
T(f)(x) = \phi(x)\;f(x)
$$
Then: $T$ is a bounded operator iff $\phi$ is an essentially bounded function.  Operator $T$ is self-adjoint iff almost all values of $\phi$ are real.  Operator $T$ is positive iff for almost all $x$, $\phi(x) \ge 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This suggests to me a consideration but I do not know if it is correct. However, let $S(f)(x)$ a bounded operator and $H = L^2(X,\mathcal F, \mu)$. Since $\| S\|\leq K$ for $K>0$, then $S$ is a bounded operator iff the components of its associated matrix is all essentially bounded functions in $x$.